# After recording a copy and paste in an Excel macro, when the macro runs, it stops at the paste with an error

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

My workaround is to have the string already present at the bottom of all the columns before the macro runs.

The macro lines are:

```
Columns("A:A").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("B5").Select
Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

The error popup reads:
Microsoft Visual Basic
Run-time error '1004':
You can't paste this here because the Copy area and paste area aren't the same size.
Select just one cell in the paste area or an area that's the same size, and try pasting again.

Comment: Note that if you copy an entire column, the only place you can paste is starting in row 1, otherwise it wont "fit".

Comment: Philip, welcome to Stack Overflow.  If the answers below are helpful, you should upvote them and choose one as the accepted answer.

Comment: To clarify: 1) The spreadsheet containing the macro (File 1) contains unique specific text in the first cell, first column, below the header row.  2) The user saves File 1 in his own folder; copies rows from another Excel file (File 2); selects the specific text cell; inserts the pasted rows above it, and runs the macro.  3) In building the macro (before my workaround) I found the unique specific string (with Find [string] > All); used the right arrow to advance to the last populated column (always the same column--not variable), and paste.  That is what caused the error.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
Application.Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Columns("A:A")).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("B5").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Or, this shorter version

```
    Application.Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Columns("A:A")).Copy Range("B5")
```

Comment: It would be appropriate to share the URL to that site here so others who come across your question can benefit from the solution that worked for you.

Comment: I need to clarify once again.  I built a macro using ordinary Excel commands.  In Edit mode in this already-built macro, I need to insert a variable declaration for the last row near the top.  In this same macro, there are several occurrences of selections of the first column, last cell.  In these selections, I need to replace the row number with the last row variable I inserted near the top of the macro.

Comment: I need to clarify once again.  I built a macro using ordinary Excel commands.  In Edit mode in this already-built macro, I inserted a variable declaration (Dim lastrow As Long, lastrow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count) for the last row.  In this same macro, there are many occurrences of the last row number, that I replaced with the last row variable, for example: Range("A1:A" & lastrow).Select.  The result was that in the columns in which I performed actions, there was an entry in the row below the last row, so perhaps I need to add "-1" to my variable.

Comment: I should add that when I try building the macro using Ctl-Home and Ctl-down arrow to select the first column last cell, I get a good result when I start with the same number of rows with which I built the macro, but when I reduce the number of rows I start with, I get the same result as with my variable--entries in the next row in the columns in which I performed actions while building the macro.